# Can't able to Download HTML of a Specific Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I am doing webparsing using C# Console Application.

My code is:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://watch.squidtv.net/");
req.BeginGetResponse(r =>
{
     var response = req.EndGetResponse(r);
     var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
     var reader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
     var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
     Console.WriteLine(str);
}, null);
```

This Code is runing fine with other URLs but when I changed URL to http://watch.squidtv.net/ then two problems occurred-

First one-  It is not downloading its html.
Second one- Its generates a sound of CPU.

Then I changed the code and used webClient like this -

```
string htmlCode = "";
htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://watch.squidtv.net");
Console.WriteLine(htmlCode);
```

But the problem is same :(
what can be the problem ???

Comment: what is it returning?

Comment: nothing but Some Garbage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the the Solution 
the probelm was HTML header in HTML header there is gzip object Encoding the httpwebrequest is not accepting the gzip header which causing the problem when i used this code the problem solved

```
   HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://watch.squidtv.net/");
        req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US))";
        string htmlCode;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            htmlCode = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you'll have to specify more in your WebRequest so that the SquidTV server can know to send you back the HTML for one idea.

Consider that in a browser there are lots of headers that get sent to the server.  If you want to take a look use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to see all the extra data that gets sent.

Firewalls could be another issue as you are sending out a request that may not be allowed and thus nothing is coming back.  This would be where I'd likely suggest intermediate tools like WireShark or Fiddler that may be useful in seeing if the request is getting out at least.

Comment: it just downloaded HTML twice but then again started the same issue